# How to develop features for deep learning from cart items data?

Tags: deep-learning, sparse, feature-engineering

I wonder how to approach building set of features to feed deep learning model (eg convnet) from cart items data:

- 5pcs of product1
- 1pcs of product5
- 2pcs of product8

Assuming 30-50 products per average shop, but no more than 150..
One way is to treat each product as a feature, when product is not in the cart than value is zero.

The problem is that usually in the cart is small subset of all avalable products which can lead to matrix where the most of values are zeros (curse of dimensionality?).

How to approach this kind of problem to build vital set of features?

Comment: look up embeddings  sparse matrices aree used to avoid wasting memory storing zeros

Comment: What are you trying to predict here?  Why are you using deep learning for a problem like this?

Comment: @MatthewDrury the problem is: predicting food delivery time from restaurant to the customer based on: ordered food, cust location and a few factors like traffic and kitchen load. Using deep learning and tensorflow are imposed.

Comment: Ok, it's not something I would reach for deep learning for as a first tool, but if imposed...